# How to get the key.value in a list where value = key.value in another list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list like this

```
    $scope.list = [{"arg0":"author1"},{"arg1":"author2"}];
    $scope.anotherlist = [{"author1":"murali"},{"author2":"krishna"}];
```

I tried this

```
    anotherlist.(list.arg0);
```

I expected the output will be converted something like this...

```
    anotherlist.author1;
```

and get the output as

```
    anotherlist.author1 = murali
```

But I am not getting anything. What should I do?

Comment: `anotherlist[0].author1;`, it's an array !

Comment: here also I need to specify author1, But in my case it is a dynamic variable. SO what I need is anotherlist.X = "murali" of "krishna" where X is author1 or author2 which is selected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.anotherlist[0][$scope.list[0]['arg0']] is what you need to get 'Murali' out :-)

Comment: In the answer we have to specify 'arg0' but in my app, I am getting the value from a cookie. so I am unable to use arg0 and arg1 as directly. What exactly I want is anotherlist.variableX = 'Murali'; where variableX = arg0 or arg1 depending on the cookie value.

Comment: just take the cookie value in a string var and use that var to access it. anotherlist.variableX is the same(almost) thing as anotherlist[variableX] 

anotherlist.variableX would be illegal, but anotherlist[variableX] would give you the results.